# can't load package: package golang.org/dl/go1.10.7@latest: can only use path@version syntax with 'go get' when trying to install another go version

Tags: go, version-control, go-modules

I'm following [this](https://go.dev/doc/manage-install) link to install and manage multiple versions of go in my ubuntu container. When I try to execute the command `go install golang.org/dl/go1.10.7@latest`, I get this error

`can't load package: package golang.org/dl/go1.10.7@latest: can only use path@version syntax with 'go get'`

I also tried with `go get golang.org/dl/go1.10.7@latest`, this exits just after printing below line `go: finding golang.org/dl latest` without downloading.

I also tried skipping the latest tag in `go install` command, this exits without any message and the version not installed. Has anyone succeeded in installing different versions of golang in ubuntu container?

Comment: Your go versions are _far_ to old. Upgrade now to something supported.

Answer (score -1):

Open `~/.bash_profile` then add:

```
$ export GOPATH=$HOME/go
$ export GOBIN=$HOME/go/bin
```

Then run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Try to run the command to install go:

```
go install golang.org/dl/go1.10.7@latest
```

Source: [SettingGOPATH](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH)